# c# database access code on android with angular nativescript

Tags: c#, android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to create a native android app by using angular nativescript because I already have angular knowledge. I do not need to re-use angular code because of a parallel existing web app. There will just be the android app.

The user will create and save some data which could be stored on a sqlite/room database on the smartphone. All links about data access I found are about JAVA.

How can I write the backend database access code with C#. Even better would be an ORM to access the local persistent store. I do not want to create a database on azure and make it available via C# web api. Thats total overhead for my situation.

Comment: I'm unaware of a solution to do this. If you only want to write C#, Xamarin might be a good fit, but no Angular to my knowledge with that option.

To be able to write C# for Android you'll need to find some solution that either converts the C# to Java or a 'wrapper' type library. Again, I'm not aware but curious what you find out on this.

You could do it all in JS/TS since you already know Angular (assuming you know TS), then there's no need for Java, but again... no C# either 

Comment: I think I am going with this plugin to stay locally on android for the development: https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite , too bad there exist no ORM wrapper for the sqlite data access.

Comment: ok I have found something really better that works with SQLite but offers ORM skills with Nativescript: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm